# UIActivityViewController crashes when sharing an UIImage I edited, but works with UIImage(named:)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm using the following code to combine two images into one

```
func combineImages() {

    //reset tent image
    self.tempImageView.image = self.selectedTent

    let size = CGSize(width: self.tempImageView.image!.size.width, height: self.tentImageView.image!.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    if let selected = self.selectedBackground {
        selected.scaleImageToSize(newSize: CGSize(width: areaSize.width, height: areaSize.height)).draw(in: areaSize)
    }

    self.tempImageView.image!.draw(in: areaSize, blendMode: CGBlendMode.normal, alpha: 0.8)

    self.combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.tempImageView.image = combinedImage
}
```

If I try to share this combinedImage using the UIAcitivityViewController, the share sheet pops up, but when I select an app (e.g. Slack), the image preview takes a while to load, the image doesn't show in the preview, and a few seconds later the share popup window just closes. Here's the code I'm using to share

```
if let imageToShare = self.combinedImage {

        let imageToShareArray = [ imageToShare ]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShareArray, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view

        // present the view controller
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

If I create an image using UIImage(named:) instead of using my combinedImage object, it all works fine and I'm able to share.

When I use the image I want, I also see this error in the output window in XCode

```
2018-09-04 10:45:28.219428-0600 MyApp[7393:4245932] [Common] _BSMachError: port 13817; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to convert your new image into data first:

```
if let imageToShare = self.combinedImage, let dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToShare, 0.8) {

   let imageToShareArray = [dataImage]
   let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShareArray, applicationActivities: nil)
   activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view

   // present the view controller
   self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'd still like to understand why my combined UIImage didn't work while the unedited ones worked and also UIImages created from assets and what that unintuitive error has to do anything, if anyone knows. But thanks for the answer, Kevin.

Comment: @Rod `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` creates an image based on the contents of the current bitmap-based graphics context. In other words a bitmap image. The UIActivityViewController doesn't work with that format. This is why you need to convert your image into data with JPEG or PNG format.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Kevin. I can sleep better now :) Stuff like this drives me crazy and I couldn't find it in the docs.